# Retrieving the image and add caption to it

Tags: android

I wanted to create an app by taking images from the sd card and add caption to it. Also I wanted to move the caption as per our wish and place it somewhere as desired and save it .can you please suggest an idea for doing this.  Also   if we want to add a caption to the existing image from SD card then , do we need to have database for doing this. or can it be saved directly to the SD card.

Comment: exactlly caption means to you is "text attached with the image" or "text on image"?

Comment: text on image...i wanted to write over image and save to memory

Comment: Look at my modified answer. Hope you will get some idea about how to implement.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use **canvas** (Custom Views) for it..

I think this is the only way to make one view (Image in one canvas) on other view (caption in other canvas) on it. So in this you have to complete knowledge of how views draw on canvas and how to move to that views. And using canvas you can also smoothly move your views on screen.

After creating custom views you can save those views in Bitmap, now you can also combine those images to one bitmap..

(Here Customeviews are ImageViews, TextViews, EditText etc..)

All the best. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**[Refer This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159186/how-do-i-write-text-over-a-picture-in-android-and-save-it)**
You can put an EditText and Write into it and after writting you first convert it to Bitmap like

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mEditText.getDrawingCache());
```

Now you can add created image bmp to your original image like this

call :

```
 Bitmap combined = combineImages(bgBitmap,bmp);
 public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap background, Bitmap foreground) {  

        int width = 0, height = 0; 
        Bitmap cs; 

        width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(); 
        height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(); 

        cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs); 
        background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, width, height, true); 
        comboImage.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null); 
        comboImage.drawBitmap(foreground, matrix, null); 

        return cs; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  USe like this. 

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs); 
    background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, width, height, true); 
    comboImage.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null); 
    comboImage.drawText("title", x, y, paint);
```