# How to add text inside bitmap or drawable?

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-imageview

Is that possible to add a dynamic text to drawable or bitmap in android? im trying do something like get some text dynamically and put that text into an image. Or at least i want to give a illusion  to the user that the text is inside that image.

Comment: try this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159186/how-do-i-write-text-over-a-picture-in-android-and-save-it/8238281#8238281

Answer (score 1):

I know you have found the solution but some people may be interested in this new way of setting Imageview with Text

Here is my **Solution:-**

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), com.cinchvalet.app.client.R.drawable.slider_pop_counter);

    Bitmap bmp = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
    String text = "Your text";
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    p.setTextSize(35);
    p.setColor(getResources().getColor(com.cinchvalet.app.client.R.color.Black));
    int width = (int) p.measureText(text);
    int yPos = (int) ((c.getHeight() / 2)
            - ((p.descent() + p.ascent()) / 2) - 10);
    c.drawText(text, (bmp.getWidth() - width) / 2, yPos, p);
```

-on your bitmap Image Draw Text On bitmap and then you can set Bitmap to your `Imageview`

-THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply overlaying a `TextView` over the `ImageView` using a relative layout?

Comment: Hmm it may work, but consider if i have to set the layout using setContenView() for each second it will  affect the performance right?

Comment: You can't call setContentView() more than once. You'd have to make your parent layout the relative layout and pass it in as a parameter, like this: setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutxmlfilename)