# Draw text on jpg image android

Tags: android, jpeg

I have an jpg image inside as a byte array. How can i dump this byte array to a jpg and write on it's canavas then save it on the sd card ?

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159186/how-do-i-write-text-over-a-picture-in-android-and-save-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) to get a `Bitmap`, then create a `Canvas` using that Bitmap, and draw the text there. Finally save it by using [`Bitmap.compress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29):

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myArray, 0, myArray.length).copy(Bitmap.Config.RGBA_8888, true); //myArray is the byteArray containing the image. Use copy() to create a mutable bitmap. Feel free to change the config-type. Consider doing this in two steps so you can recycle() the immutable bitmap.
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
canvas.drawText("Hello Image", xposition, yposition, textpaint); //x/yposition is where the text will be drawn. textpaint is the Paint object to draw with.

OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dstfile); //dstfile is a File-object that you want to save to. You probably need to add some exception-handling here.
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPG, 100, os); //Output as JPG with maximum quality.
os.flush();
os.close();//Don't forget to close the stream.
```

Comment: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor i get this exception. Any ideea what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: @opc0de ah, forgot about that, the `decodeByteArray()` returns an immutable (unmodifiable) bitmap, so you can't draw on directly on it.
I added the `.copy()` command in the example. This creates an identical bitmap that is mutable.

Answer (score 2):

1. Decode byte array using [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29)

   1. Create a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)
   2. Draw [text](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) on it
   3. [Save](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) your bitmap to [SD storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I love to see how people -1 this answer. I guess it's the same kind of... emm... developers... who prefer Ctrl-C Ctrl-V answers :)