# place text over capture image in Android?

Tags: android

I am working on an fun application in android. In which I need to capture an image and just after that before saving I need to add some text over the captured image. 
Is it possible to edit captured image at run time in android please suggest me.
Thaanxx in advance..!

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678377/overlaying-text-or-edittext-on-captured-image) could help you

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159186/how-do-i-write-text-over-a-picture-in-android-and-save-it

Comment: Ya, the text will be like shots of a horse character and then add
the character to their camera screen after taking pic.

Answer (score 2):

If you use default intent to capture the image use the following code. Wherever you touch the image the text will be placed. cp, imageview should be in your layout. And RelativeLayout rl is the id of your layout.

```
ImageView cp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_cp);
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);


        cp.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("touched x val of cap img >>", event.getX() + "");
                Log.v("touched y val of cap img >>", event.getY() + "");
                x = (int) event.getX();
                y = (int) event.getY();
                RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay_lin);
                TextView iv = new TextView(Capture_Image.this);
                iv.setText("checking......");
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.leftMargin = x;
                params.topMargin = y;
                rl.addView(iv, params);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            cp.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }

    }
```