# Write text on image and save the image with text in the SD card without drawing it on the screen

Tags: android, canvas, view, bitmap, android-custom-view

I have been struggling with this problem for quite a long time now. **I want to take an image from the resources folder and write some text, dynamically generated as part of a process, and then save the final image with text in the SD Card.** I know how to write the files in the SD card. I'm unable to write the text on the image.

I created a RelativeLayout with imageview and textview and saved it to SD card but later realized that I don't have to draw the view. So, couldn't go with this.

Again, I would like to stress the point that my application requires not to draw the bitmap on the current screen.

Could anyone offer any solutions here?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dont use an image view for this.

Use canvas!

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
Bitmap alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, paint);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
paint.setTextSize(20); 
canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint);
```

Then just save 'alteredBitmap' to the SD card

Comment: Thank you Richard! Such an easy solution. :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please read my comment on MKJParekh's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159186/how-do-i-write-text-over-a-picture-in-android-and-save-it

Comment: Can you please any one tell me that "How to add multi line text" with the above sample code ?