# Android- Write over a image and Save It as Png

Tags: java, android, image, text

I want to make an application, where some pictures are there already or users can upload pictures. And then they can write on it on some specific places. Any open source project like this?

I need to learn about it. I need to know something from Android Studio versions.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: This is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159186/how-do-i-write-text-over-a-picture-in-android-and-save-it

Answer (score 0):

This is an example method how to add a text to a bitmap.

```
private Bitmap addTextToBitmap(Bitmap b) {
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    Paint p = new Paint();

    p.setTextSize(100);
    p.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    c.drawText("Example text", X_POSITION, Y_POSITION, p);
    b = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
    return b;
}
```